# If a martingale $(M_n)$ has uniformly bounded $p^{th}$ moment, then it's uniformly integrable.

Tags: probability, martingales

Let $(M_n)$ a martingale s.t. $p^{th}$ moment is uniformly bounded. Then $(M_n)$ is uniformly integrable. (So, I'm not sure if it's for all $p^{th}$ moment or at least one).

So let $p$ s.t. $$\mathbb E[|M_n|^p]\leq C.$$
Then, $$\mathbb E[|M_n|]\leq C.$$
Now, $$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb E[|M_n|\boldsymbol 1_{|M_n|\geq K}]\leq C.$$

Why this would implies that $$\lim_{P\to \infty }\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb E[|M_n|\boldsymbol 1_{|M_n|\geq K}]=0\ \ ?$$

Comment: It does not.  You gave up too much in the second line, because $E[|M_n|] \le C$ does not imply uniform integrability.  You really need to exploit the fact that $p$ is strictly greater than 1.

Comment: The hypothesis should be that there exists some $p>1$ and some $C$ such that $E[|M_n|^p] \le C$.  It does not need to hold for all $p$ (if it did then that would force $M_n$ just to be uniformly bounded).  By the way, this proposition is true for any sequence of random variables; they do not have to be a martingale.

Comment: I think if any sequence  of random variables has bounded $p$th moment with $p>1$ then it is uniformly integrable by using De La Vallee Poussin's characterization of uniform integrability. See here: http://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2014/03/09/de-la-vallee-poussin-on-uniform-integrability/

Answer (score 1):

We require $p>1$, the statement does not hold for $p=1$. In particular, by trying to prove this by only using that $\mathbb E[|M_n|]$ is bounded, you are doomed to fail. However, we can try directly by Holder's inequality:

$$ \mathbb E[|M_n|\mathbf 1_{|M_n| \ge K}] \le \left(\mathbb E[|M_n|^p]\right)^{1/p}\left(\mathbb E[\mathbf 1_{|M_n| \ge K}^q]\right)^{1/p} \le C^{1/q}\mathbb P(|M_n|\ge K)^{1/q},$$

where $q$ satisfies $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$. Applying Chebyshev's inequality, we have

$$\mathbb P(|M_n| \ge K) \le \frac{\mathbb E[|M_n|^p]}{K^p} \le \frac{C}{K^p},$$

and plugging this back into our first inequality, we find

$$ \mathbb E[|M_n|\mathbf 1_{|M_n| \ge K}] \le C^{1/p}\left(\frac{C}{K^p}\right)^{1/q} = \frac{C}{K^{p/q}}, $$
which is independent of $n$ and tends to zero as $K\to\infty$.

Comment: Much easier (a standard trick to prove sufficiency of the de la Vallee Poussin criterion): $$\mathbb E[|M_n|\mathbf 1_{|M_n| \ge K}] \le K^{1-p}\mathbb E[|M_n|^p\mathbf 1_{|M_n| \ge K}]  \le K^{1-p}\mathbb E[|M_n|^p].$$